# Display messages through cURL (json) (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to display messages starting with a specific id, for example, I chose id = 4. It works

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/api/unread/4
```

But told me that the curl request was written incorrectly, he should send Json and return Json, Sorry, maybe I wrote an example incorrectly, but it should look something like this -

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{id=4"}" localhost:8080/api/unread
```

RestService

```
@Service
public class RestService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    public Message saveMessage(Message message) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/save";

        return this.restTemplate.postForObject(url, message, Message.class);
    }

    public void updateMessage(long id, Message message) {
        String url = String.format("http://localhost:8080/api/update/%d", id);

        this.restTemplate.put(url, message);
    }

    public List<Message> getLast() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/last";

        String json = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Message>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

RestController

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Resource
    private final MessageService messageService;

    public RestController(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/save")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveMessage(@RequestBody Message chatMessage) {
        return messageService.add(chatMessage);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/last")
    public String getLasts() {
        return new Gson().toJson(messageService.getLast());
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/unread")
    public void getUnreadMessages() {

        timerTask.run();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/unread/{id}")
    public List<Message> getUnreadById(@PathVariable ("id") long id) {
        return messageService.getUnreadById(id);
    }
```

MessageServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;
    private final PageRequest lastRequest;

    private List<Long> chekedMessages = new ArrayList<>();


    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        lastRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody  Message message) {
        try {
            message.setTime(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            repository.save(message);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Сообщение сохранено", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(e.toString(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getLast() {
        List<Message> result = repository.findAll(lastRequest).getContent();

        return result.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Message::getId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getUnreadById(long id) {
        return repository.getUnreadById(id);
    }



    @Override
    public String getUnreadMessages() {
        List<Message> out = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Message> unchekedMessages = repository.findAll();
        for (Message message: unchekedMessages) {
            if (!chekedMessages.contains(message.getId())) {
                chekedMessages.add(message.getId());
                out.add(message);
            }
        }
        return new Gson().toJson(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMessage(long id, Message message) {
        if (repository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
            message.setId(id);
            repository.save(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly explain your question in a better way.

Comment: How can I write the curl request correctly,

Comment: for a POST call?

Comment: I wrote but they told me that this is wrong. You need to write something like this - curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{id=4"}" localhost:8080/api/unread

Comment: ok now maybe I get your question

Comment: Yes, let's say I enter id = 4, it should show all messages starting from id=4

Comment: but that is a GET call, the unread API why do we require a JSON body? Normally GET requests only have parameters along with request, did you ask if API needed to be GET or POST?

Comment: Ideally GET shouldn't have a JSON body

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following curl request.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json'  'http://localhost:8080/api/unread/4'
```

Comment: Need to send Jason and get him back. Example - curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{id=4"}" localhost:8080/api/unread

Comment: Integrate swagger it will generate curl request for your API.

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080/api/save {"time": 2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000,"unread": true, "message": "asd","from":"Vadim"}

Comment: curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json'  -d '{ \ 
   "time": "2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000", \ 
   "unread": "true", \ 
   "message": "asd", \ 
   "from": "Vadim" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:8080/api/save'